# Windows Scipt Host Error when trying to run vbs script

Tags: r, vbscript, shiny

When I try to run the run.vbs file I get the following error

"Windows Script Host"

Script:

Line: 2

Char: 1

Error: 0x800700D8

Code: 800700D8

Source: (null)

This works fine on my desktop (windows 7 - 64 bit) but not on my laptop (windows 7 - 32 bit). Anyone knows why that is and how I can fix it?

By the way the run.vbs is:

`Randomize`

`CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\R.exe CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave runShinyApp.R" & " " & RND & " ", 0, False`

It is used to run an R shiny application.
(Tutorial I followed:

http://blog.analytixware.com/2014/03/packaging-your-shiny-app-as-windows.html?showComment=1444128440802#c7486216415064021925
)

Comment: Path to the R.exe not same on the 32bit Win7?

Comment: The path should be the same as R portable is installed in the same folder as the shiny files and the vbs script. The folder hierarchy is the same as in the tutorial I have linked. I probably should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. The problem is that the laptop was 32bit, everything seems to work fine if you change

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\R.exe CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave runShinyApp.R" & " " & RND & " ", 0, False
```

to

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\i386\R.exe CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave runShinyApp.R" & " " & RND & " ", 0, False
```